# handsontable - validate the whole table after changes

Tags: handsontable

I've setup a handsontable with a csv data source. After adding some validation rules everything seems to work fine.

I used the 'afterValidate' event to inform the user if the cell they just edited failed validation. However, I want to run validation on all cells so if there are any errors the user is notified.

```
afterValidate: function (isValid,value,row,prop,source) {
    if(isValid) document.getElementById('validated_label').innerHTML = 'Working';
else document.getElementById('validated_label').innerHTML = 'Not Working'; 
},
```

EDIT: Managed to solve by using the validateCells method available in the API :)

Comment: Please let me know how you didit..